# Touching unoccupied screen location in Blackberry fires focused field listener?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, touch

I'm developing an application on 9900 where both Trackball and touch screen are available. 
In my application, I have a screen which contains two buttons, the strange behavior is that:
 If I set the focus ***using the trackball*** to the second button, and then  I touch any empty location in the screen, the change listener of the second button get fired ? **I want nothing to happen if the user wrongly clicks empty space and doesn't touch the second button, how to do this ?**

Comment: Please post the code you use for this screen with two buttons.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, for those who are interested, you may use this code in your Image button class:

```
private boolean isTouchOutside;

protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
    isTouchOutside = message.getX(1) < 0 || message.getX(1) > getWidth() || message.getY(1) < 0 || message.getY(1) > getHeight();
    return super.touchEvent(message); 
}

protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    if(! isTouchOutside)
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
    return true;
}
```